# How to fetch multiple images stored in Mysql using php?

Tags: php, mysql, image

I have inserted the multiple images to the table using the unique-Id separated by commas and Now I want fetch those images from the database and display it separately,

In database the images are stored in category wise, each category having the images in following format.

```
142375784eb96ef5671468328855.jpg,133305784eb96ef9f01468328855.jpg,224995784eb96efcb31468328855.jpg
```

I have tried the following code

```
<?php
$query  = "SELECT * FROM book_post";
$res    = mysqli_query($con, $query);
    if(mysqli_num_rows($res) > 0)
        {
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res))
            {
    $temp = array();
    $row['book_image']=trim($row['book_image'], '/,');
    $temp   = explode(',', $row['book_image']);
    $temp   = array_filter($temp);
    foreach($temp as $image){
    $images[]="images/book/".$row['book_category']."/".trim( str_replace(array('[',']') ,"" ,$image ) );
    }
?>
<div class="col-sm-4">
   <div class="product-image-wrapper">
     <div class="single-products">
       <div class="productinfo text-center">
         <img src="<?php echo $images[0];?>" alt="" />
            <h2>&#8377;<?php echo $row['book_price'];?></h2>
            <p><?php echo $row['book_name'];?></p>
       </div>
       <div class="product-overlay">
         <div class="overlay-content">
           <h2><?php echo $row['book_name'];?></h2>
            <p>Author: <?php echo $row['book_author'];?></p>
         </div>
       </div>
    </div>
   </div>
</div>
<?php }
}
?>
```

Here the problem is, It fetching the first images and displaying it in every category. I want to display the images in category wise

Help me out guys..

Comment: Currently you get same(first) image for all category

Comment: yes, I want to display by category wise. Is it possible?

Comment: Sure. Seeing as how you've given zero insight into what your schema is, and as we're not psychic, you're going to have to explain better (Hint: `SHOW CREATE TABLE` helps us a lot) or figure it out yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to `re-initialize` the `image array`

So change the following

```
foreach($temp as $image){
    $images[]="images/book/".$row['book_category']."/".trim( str_replace(array('[',']') ,"" ,$image ) );
}
```

Into

```
$images = array();
foreach($temp as $image){
    $images[]="images/book/".$row['book_category']."/".trim( str_replace(array('[',']') ,"" ,$image ) );
}
```

So you will get first image for category/post wise.